# QtCreator creates unwanted windows

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator, qml

This issue occurs on raring with the build "qtcreator 2.8.1-0ubuntu1~raring1~test1", the latest from the software center. It works fine in general, but if you click on "Welcome" and than on "Develop", "Examples" or "Tutorials" some unwanted windows appear. Here is an image of the behaviour

[image: wrong behaviour here]

Furthermore, there is a specific pattern. If you click on "Develop", four windows appear. If you click on "Examples", two windows appear. And if you click on "Tutorials", one window appears. After that, you can't use the IDE anymore. Sometimes I have to kill the process with kill on the terminal.

Except from this issue everything works fine. You can create projects, modify code, build it and run it.

Comment: I am running 2.8.1 and it's just fine. Maybe this is an Ubuntu packaging/dependency/patch bug, try reporting this.

Comment: I did a while ago. Unfortunately I didn't get any answer to this, not on askubuntu and not on launchpad. So my last idea was stackoverflow...